# OpenMP for reduction clause giving invailid identifier

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I am using openMP parallel for reduction clause to sum two variables `(area_inner_grain_total and perimeter_total)` in parallel threads. The code looks like:

```
void lagrange_multiplier(const mat &LV_Psi, double     
&area_inner_grain_total, double &lagrange_multiplier_vol_constr)
{
mat dirac_delta;
get_dirac_delta(LV_Psi, dirac_delta);

mat LV_heaviside_fn;
get_Heavyside_function(LV_Psi, LV_heaviside_fn);

area_inner_grain_total = 0.0;
double perimeter_total = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < LV_Num_Grid_Points; i++)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:area_inner_grain_total,perimeter_total)
    for (int j = 0; j < LV_Num_Grid_Points; j++)
    {
        area_inner_grain_total += (double)(LV_heaviside_fn(i,j) * LV_h * LV_h);
        perimeter_total += (double)(dirac_delta(i,j) * LV_h * LV_h);
    }   
}

lagrange_multiplier_vol_constr = (double((-area_inner_grain_total+initial_area)/perimeter_total);
}
```

However, I get the error:

*‘area_inner_grain_total’ has invalid type for ‘reduction’   in line 
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:area_inner_grain_total,perimeter_total)*

The OpenMP documentation says that I can use any scalar variable and perform *+* operation  easily using reduction clause. Why am I getting this error ? What is wrong here ?

Comment: I feel like I've had this issue before... I think it might have been because `area_inner_grain_total` isn't a double, but a reference to a double. Try creating local variables, using those in your loop and reduce them, then set your references equal to those before leaving the function and see if that helps.

Comment: @RyanP Thanks for your comment. You are right. I tried making a local variable and it worked. But, why will the reference to a double not work ?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not sure. I'm not an OpenMP expert by any means, so I don't know if that is intended, or it just depends on the implementation of OpenMP in your compiler... just not sure.

Comment: OpenMP before version 4.0 does not allow C++ reference types to be listed in the `reduction` clause.